# Laravel custom belongsTo dynamic binding

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models, `Building` and `Apartment`. Building has a column named `address` and apartment has a column named `addresss`

I want to add relation like this:

```
public function building() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Building::class, 'addresss', 'address');
}
```

But then this gives null:

```
Apartment::first()->building
```

Even if this works:

```
Apartment::first()->building()->first()
```

So what should I do to get it to work using only this:

```
Apartment::first()->building
```

Answer (score 0):

If i kept it right the Apartment is part of the building?

That is why you set the Relation in Model Apartment:

```
public function building() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Building::class, 'addresss', 'address');
}
```

When i use the belongsTo Relation, I just mention the class and do not append anymore inside the brackets like in this case:

```
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

What is the purpose of mentioning appartment's addresss aswell in the relation ? Have you set the foreign key's propely & set a hasMany Relationship in the Building-Model ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had a column in apartments table named `building`, removing this fixed it